# How is this "that" used? Can "that" be used in 'nonrestrictive relative clause'?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> It is impossible to pass very quickly from one kind of work to another, **that** is carried on in a different place and with quite different tools.

In this sentence, I think "another" is the antecedent of the relative pronoun "that" in bold. (If I am wrong in this step, please tell me.)

If I am right, how can "that" be used after ","? As far as I know, "that" cannot be used in a nonrestrictive relative clause.

Comment: Did you write this? If not, where is this from?

Comment: This is from "The Wealth of Nations" by Adam Smith.

Comment: There is no comma in the original text. Someone has added it by mistake. See para 7 here:[link](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/smith-adam/works/wealth-of-nations/book01/ch01.htm).

Comment: @BillJ I dont' think that's the original. Could you check this out?: [link](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=A5moyserOFIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=The+wealth+of+nations&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLyfDD0sjmAhUtyIsBHapuCAIQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=The%20wealth%20of%20nations&f=false) The sentence is on the seventh line from the top of page 14.

Comment: @BillJ  Also, if you google the sentence, you can find many other results which use "," before "that" in the sentence. I assume that your link and a few other sites show an edited sentence.